# Multiple join conditions OR. SQL to Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I've been trying to convert this SQL-query to Linq for some time now without success. I've found out that it aint possible to use OR condition in the join with linq, so I've tried the same SQL-query but with subqueries instead. The subquery question wont work at all, it displays wrong data.

The sqlquery with JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Fname FROM Friends
JOIN Users On Users.UserID = UserID2 OR Users.UserID = UserID1
WHERE UserID1 = 1 OR UserID2 = 1
AND Users.UserID != 1 AND Friends.PendingFriendRequest = 0
```

The sqlquery with Subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Fname FROM Friends, Users
WHERE Users.UserID = Friends.UserID1 OR Users.UserID = Friends.UserID2
AND UserID1 = 1 OR UserID2 = 1 
AND Users.UserID != 1 And Friends.PendingFriendRequest = 0
```

Comment: It does not work even if you add brackets: `WHERE (UserID1 = 1 OR UserID2 = 1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query if first where condition `UserID1 = 1` matches then rest part of the query will be ignored.

Try adding brackets to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Fname FROM Friends
JOIN Users On Users.UserID = UserID2 OR Users.UserID = UserID1
WHERE (UserID1 = 1 OR UserID2 = 1)
AND Users.UserID != 1 AND Friends.PendingFriendRequest = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right - multiple join conditions with OR are not permitted in a linq join, as only equijoins and group joins are supported.

To achieve your scenario one solution would be to use a union in linq instead.

eg:

```
var q = (from u in
            (from u1 in users
             join f1 in friends on u1.userId equals f1.user1Id
             where !f1.PendingFriendRequest
             select new {u1.Fname, FriendsWithId = f1.UserId, UserId = u2.UserId})
            .Union(from u2 in users
             join f2 in friends on u2.userId equals f2.user2Id
             where !f2.PendingFriendRequest
             select new {u2.Fname, FriendsWithId = f2.UserId, UserId = u2.UserId})
         where u.FriendsWithId == 1
               && u.UserId != 1
         select u.Fname
         ).Distinct();
```